# Why mapPartitionsWithIndex cause a shuffle in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle, rdd

I'm new in Spark. I'm checking the shuffling issues in a test application and I don't know why in my program the `mapPartitionsWithIndex` method cause a shuffle! As you can see in picture my initial RDD has two 16MB partition and Shuffle write about 49.8 MB.
I know that the `map` or `mapPartition` or `mapPartitionsWithIndex` are not shuffling transformation like `groupByKey` but I see that they also cause shuffle in Spark. Why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are performing some join/group operation after mapPartitionsWithIndex and that is causing shuffle.

you can establish it by modifying your code.

current code

```
val rdd = inputRDD1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(....)
val outRDD = rdd.join(inputRDD2)
```

Modified code

```
val rdd = inputRDD1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(....)
println(rdd.count)
```

Comment: But, if so why spark considers this method as a Stage and doesn't consider the next join/group operation as the final operation in stage?

Comment: A stage corresponds to a collection of tasks that all execute the same code, each on a different subset of the data. Each stage contains a sequence of transformations that can be completed without shuffling the full data. - http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/

Comment: I know, but I remember that the final operation in each Stage is usually a shuffle operation, and if we assume after this map method there is a join/group operation then it should be as the final operation in this stage and shows instead of mapPartitionWithIndex.

Comment: no, that will be next stage. for a simple join workflow 3 stages are required. 1st for loading rdd1+transformation + shuffle output, 2nd for loading rdd2 +transformation + shuffle output and 3rd for reading shuffle output and joining these feeds and then save to disk or do anything else.

Comment: I modified the code as you told me, i.e `count` the rdd immediately after `mapPartitionWithIndex` but there is no sign why shuffling happens. http://i.imgur.com/aPAYFpx.png

Comment: I think you haven't removed join/group part which is causing shuffle. count will just establish that mapPartitionsWithIndex is not causing shuffle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77776/discussion-between-farzad-and-sb).